# how to get azure AD access_token for ServicePrincipal for power bi reports

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need to get Azure AD Access token from Vanilla Javascript code to use it for Power BI reports. I could get some working samples in .net from https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples. But as the website that am using built on third part wordpress like CMS I can't use it.

All i need is to get Azure AD access token from vanilla javascript or either some post man request?

I have below configuration values for my power BI report,

"AzureAd": {
"AuthenticationMode": "ServicePrincipal",
"AuthorityUri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/",
"ClientId": "XXXXXXXXX",
"TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
"Scope": [ "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" ],
"PbiUsername": "",
"PbiPassword": "",
"ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXX"
},
"PowerBI": {
"WorkspaceId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
"ReportId": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
},

I have tried few javascript samples from below github repo but they did not work,
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser.

Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would like to get Azure AD access token for PowerBI with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)(app-only). You could use [`@azure/msal-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node?activeTab=readme) in javascript, sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/request.md#client-credentials-flow).

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

// Initialize MSAL
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "Enter_the_Application_Id_Here",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Id_Here",
        clientSecret: "Enter_the_Client_Secret_Here",
   }
};
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Requesting tokens
const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: [ 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default' ],
};

const tokenResponse = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
```

Comment: I am able to get token. need to work on embedding it to get power bi reports using power-bi client npm package. If you know any samples for that please provide if possible. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Why not calling the [Get Reports Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports) to get power bi reports directly? You could generate an embed token with this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/embed-token-generate-token): `POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken`.

Comment: @Mahesh How are you able to get the token? I keep getting cors error

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for my auth.js file:

````
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// Licensed under the MIT license.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const getAccessToken = async function () {

    try {

        const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

        // Create a config variable that store credentials from config.json
        // replace with
        let config = require("../config/config.json");
        
        let authorityUri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + `${config.tenantId}`

        // Initialize MSAL
        const msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: `${config.clientId}`,
                authority: `${authorityUri}`,
                clientSecret: `${config.clientSecret}`,
            }
        };

        const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

        // Requesting tokens
        const tokenRequest = {
            scopes: ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'],
        };

        // async function tokenResponse() { 
        let response = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

module.exports.getAccessToken = getAccessToken;```
````